# Export of particular value from list in Java

Tags: java

I have one below list

```
List<Customer> customers = customer.getCustomerDetails();


Class Customer {
    String name;
    String age;
    String dob;

   // getter and setter

}
```

> What I want, I need only `List<String> dobList` from existing List
>   (`List<Customer>`)

Where `dobList` contains `customer DOB`

I have tried below code ::

```
        List<String> dobList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Customer customer : customers) {
            dobList.add(customer.getDOB);
        }
```

Comment: what have you tried? what hinders you from using java 7 features?

Comment: http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/

Answer (score 1):

In your approach

```
List<String> dobList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Customer customer : customers) {
        dobList.add(customer.getDOB());
    }
```

In **java 8** you can use below code as reference

```
List<String> dobsList = customersList.stream()
                               .map(Customer::getdob)
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

customer.getCustormerDetails().stream().map(Custorer::getDob).collect(Collectors.toList());

Answer (score 0):

what you have is correct, you just have a small syntax error. Do:

```
dobList.add(customer.getDOB());
```

you just forgot the parenthesis at the end of your method call, assuming getDOB() is an existing method

Answer (score 0):

its very simple. Please read some basics of stream.

```
List<String> dobList =  customers.stream()
                                 .map(customer -> cutomer.getDOB)
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```